# how to configure the way of inserting double quote in auctex with smartparens

Tags: emacs, auctex

recently I updated emacs package and found double quotes were not inserted as regular double quotes (") any more.

Instead, it insert pair of LaTeX double quotes `` and '' on ". On the second typing of ", it reverts to a single LaTeX double quote ``.

I would like to setup auctex and smartparens such that

1. make a pair of regular double quotes (") inserted, and return to a pair of LaTeX double quote on the second typing of ".

or

2. make a pair of regular double quotes (") inserted, and return to a single regular double quote on the second typing of ".

my emacs setup for smartparens and auctex is as follows:

```
(use-package smartparens
    :ensure t
    :init
    (progn
        (use-package smartparens-config)
        (smartparens-global-mode t)
        (show-smartparens-global-mode t)
        )
    :config
    (progn
        (setq smartparens-strict-mode t)
        (sp-local-pair 'emacs-lisp-mode "'" nil :when '(sp-in-string-p))
        )
```

```
(use-package tex
    :ensure auctex
    :init
    (setq-default TeX-master nil)
    (setq TeX-auto-save t) ;; Enable parse on load
    (setq TeX-parse-self t) ;; Enable parse on save
    (setq TeX-engine 'xetex)
    (setq TeX-command-extra-options "-shell-escape")
    (setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
    (setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
    (setq TeX-quote-after-quote 1)
    (setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
    (setq latex-preview-pane-enable t)

    :config
    (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex) ; with AUCTeX LaTeX mode
    (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode) ; with AUCTeX LaTeX math mode
    (add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex) ; with Emacs latex mode
    (add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (TeX-fold-mode 1)))
    (add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (outline-minor-mode 1)))
    (add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (TeX-PDF-mode 1)))
    (add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'reftex-mode)
    (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
            (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "<f10>") 'TeX-command-master)
            (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c `") 'TeX-error-overview)
            ))
    )
```